# stuck at grub rescue on boot, no bios, no live cd, ls returns hd0

Tags: boot, grub2, livecd, elementary-os

I have an external hard drive with elementary os on it, and when I took it out my preinstalled windows 8 laptop, it came up with the "error: no such device:'hex number' grub rescue>". I can't boot from the external hdd, no live usbs, can't get to bios, and when I type in ls, it comes back with only "(hd0)".

I have found articles that tell how to fix either just the ls problem, or just the boot error problem, but none of them will let me fix all of them. Ask ubuntu is telling me that this is off topic on their site. At this point, I don't think that I really need the files on the computer, but just an operating system on it. Either the elementary, or some way to get back to windows 8. If anyone can help me just install any kind of os on it, I would be overjoyed.

The computer is an Asus X502C. When I put in "find /boot/vmlinuz", it just says that "find" is an unknown command.

Comment: What is the output of `find /boot/vmlinuz`? (Add that to your question.)

Comment: @HaukeLaging the OP is stuck at the grub rescue screen, how would they be able to run `find`?

Comment: As I told you in your [ubuntu.se] post, if you have found solutions for one of the two problems, try it and tell us if it worked or _how_ it failed. Also, what do you mean by "no live usbs"? You don't have any or you can't boot from them? How are you attempting to get into the BIOS? If you have no BIOS, this is a hardware problem. Have you actually _removed_ the hard drive from your laptop?

Comment: @terdon I am not talking about Gnu `find` but about GRUB `find`... Execute `grub` in order to get a GRUB shell and there execute `find /boot/vmlinuz`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging grub2 [doesn't seem to](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands) have that.

Comment: @terdon I am not familiar with GRUB2. It seems that `find` has been replaced by `ls`.