# Recovering from 'grub rescue>' crash

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, boot-loader, busybox

*Originally posted to AskUbuntu.com ...*

> [AskUbuntu has adopted a policy of closing](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li) questions about EOL
>   (End Of Life) versions. There's a vocal contingent to remove them as well.
>   To prevent possible loss of this popular question (342335 views to date),
>   am placing a revised version here.
>   --- docsalvager

*The "classic" system...*

- Puppy Linux 5.2.8 (Lucid) based on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)
- [GRUB 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) boot loader

[GRUB 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) puts a number of `*.mod` files (kernel modules) in `/boot/grub`. Deleting these files (thinking they were misplaced sound files) resulted in failure on reboot and the prompt `grub rescue>`.

*How to recover in this situation?*

Comment: Seems like a dumb question.. obviously you either restore the deleted files from backup, or reinstall grub ( and there are plenty of questions about how to do that already )

Comment: It would seem to me that booting into rescue mode off the DVD and reinstalling grub from there would probably be ideal. It's probably a lot more straightforward for most people since the mentioned data loss should be restricted to the files in the package.

Comment: Not to say that I don't think fishing the specific files out of the initrd isn't clever. I Just think it's likely to confuse people as it is to help. Booting into rescue/recovery mode is a more common procedure.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This answer is for others out there that DocSalvager's answer doesn't work for.

1. I followed DocSalvager's use of `ls` to find the correct hard drive partition.  In my case it was `(hd0,msdos5)`.
2. Then I executed the following commands to get back to the normal grub boot loader screen.

   ```
   grub rescue>  set boot=(hd0,msdos5)
   grub rescue>  set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
   grub rescue>  insmod normal  
   grub rescue>  normal
   ```
3. After booting into Ubuntu I repaired the grub boot loader with the following commands from the terminal.

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

Please reference [this source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc_y7OYzXtQ) for a visual walk through of this process.

Comment: Perfect - exactly the help I needed to boot! I also ran `sudo update-grub` before `grub-install`, because my partition layout had changed.

Comment: After doing all these steps, I can log into system normally but I shut down and reboot and got "ELF sections outside core" error.

Comment: the `boot` (as in `set boot`) environment variable is undocumented (info, html). how do i get information on its purpose?

Comment: note that the prefix will depend on the disk layout - e.g. a modern system with a seperate `/boot` may have something like `set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/grub2`

Comment: the command listed under point 3. worked for me but I also had to execute the command  sudo update-grub2 right after the sudo grub-install /dev/sda2
That's all I did to fix the problem.

Comment: After running this command `insmod normal` I get: `symbol \`grub_calloc\` not found.`

Comment: Perhaps, it's worth to mention that `(hd0,msdos5)` is the same as `(hd0,5)`. Related: https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-rg-en-3/s1-grub-terminology.html

Comment: What if the `insmod normal` returns `error: symbol 'grub_file_filters_all' not found`?

Answer (score 34):

**Recovering from a grub rescue crash ...**

- `grub rescue>` does not support `cd`, `cp` or any other filesystem commands except its own variation of `ls` which is really a kind of `find` command.
- So first, had to find the partition with the `/boot` directory containing the `vmlinuz` and other boot image files...

  ```
  grub rescue>  ls  
  (hd0,4) (hd0,3) (hd0,2) (hd0,1)  

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,4)/boot
  ... some kind of 'not found' message

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,3)/boot
  ... some kind of 'not found' message

  grub rescue>  ls (hd0,2)/boot
  ... grub ... initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic ... vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic
  ```

  - `ls` without arguments returns the four partitions on this system.
  - `ls (hd0,4)/boot` does not find a `/boot` directory on partition `(hd0,4)`.
  - `ls (hd0,3)/boot` does not find a `/boot` directory on partition `(hd0,3)`.
  - `ls (hd0,2)/boot` finds a `/boot` directory on partition `(hd0,2)` and it contains a `vmlinuz` and other boot image files we want.
- To manually boot from the `grub rescue>` prompt ...

  ```
  grub rescue>  set root=(hd0,2)/boot  
  grub rescue>  insmod linux  
  grub rescue>  linux (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic  
  grub rescue>  initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic  
  grub rescue>  boot
  ```

  - Set `root` to use the `/boot` directory on partition `(hd0,2)`.
  - Load grub module `linux`.
  - Set that module to use the kernel image `vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic`.
  - Set initrd(init RAM disk) to use the image `initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic`.
  - Boot Linux.
- This boots to a [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/screenshot.html) commandline prompt which has all the basic filesystem commands (*and then some!*).
- Then could move the `*.mod` files back to the `/boot/grub` directory ...

  ```
  busybox>  cd /boot  
  busybox>  mv mod/* grub
  busybox>  reboot
  ```
- *Successful Reboot!*

*See also ...*

- [stuck at grub rescue on boot, no bios, no live cd, ls returns hd0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119965/27437)
- [recovering from grub rescue crash (AskUbuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)
- [how to fix error unknown filesystem grub rescue (AskUbuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)
- [A nice Grub 2 ls command reference page](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20CLI%20Mode%20Commands.html#cli_ls)
- [BusyBox (website)](http://www.busybox.net/screenshot.html)
- [BusyBox online emulator](http://www.busybox.net/live_bbox/live_bbox.html)

Comment: I cannot find any boot folder at the root level in the BusyBox

Comment: The vmlinuz,... boot images you are looking for could be in the top-level root filesystem so try using just a slash. That will also show top-level directories. If the boot images are not in the top-level root, you can start trying the most promising of the directories till you find them. For example: `ls (hd0,1)/`, `ls (hd0,2)/`, `ls (hd0,2)/initramfs/`, etc..

Comment: In my case, after running `ls (hd0,7)/boot`, it shows `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'`.

Comment: There are less than 7 partitions on drive hd0. It may also be that there is some unallocated space on the drive that is not part of any partition.

Comment: I had to set the prefix to /boot/grub before being allowed to run insmod linux!

Comment: Cant find any boot folder cd /boot/. When trying / it says permission denied.

Comment: Grub does not have `cd` command. The `(hd0,1)`, etc. are the way Grub addresses devices and partitions. Thus, `(hd0,1)` is the first partition on the first device recognized at boot up. `(hd0,1)/` is the top-level directory (also called the "root directory" but that's  confusing due to the directory under it named `/root`). `(hd1,2)/boot` would be the `/boot` directory on the second partition on the second device. Device# starts at 0, partition# starts at 1.

Comment: Can't cd to boot. Using ls I find dev, etc, conf, lib, scripts, proc, root, var, run, bin, usr, tmp, kernel, lib64, sbin, init, sys folders only.

Comment: You have to go through all the steps in the bullet list with the `boot` command item running successfully before you get to a Busybox commandline. It is Busybox that has a `cd` command.

Comment: `insmod linux` results in error: `symbol 'grub_file_filters_all' not found`