# Cannot boot into Linux off live USB

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, dual-boot, live-usb

I am trying to dual boot Linux on my laptop (Dell XPS 15) which is running Windows 10 Pro. I did not have any problem dual booting the two operating systems on my desktop.

I cannot boot up **ANY** Linux Distro, I have tried Mint, Ubuntu and Elementary OS. Whenever I try to boot from a live USB, I get the this message on all attempts:

**GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1**

**Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists are possible device or file completions.**

**grub>**

When I type in "boot" I get the error: **you need to load the kernel first.**

Secure boot is disabled, and I have tried both in legacy and UEFI BIOS mode. I have never come across this error before, what causes it?

Comment: Did you tinker with legacy support for USB in BIOS? BTW please read  the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and leave out distractions and chit-chat in your posts, that will be appreciated by all future readers.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the heads up. No I have not changed any USB settings in the BIOS. The only USB options in there are: **USB Emulation**, **USB Powershare**, **USB Wake Support** and **USB debug**.

Comment: I would at least set USB emulation to **on** if it is not already set, I assumed that GRUB would use the BIOS to read the data from USB, but I am not 100% sure if it does (if not, some new USB chipset might be the problem).

Comment: Your laptop has partly succeeded in its attempt to boot the live USB otherwise you wouldn't see the GRUB prompt. But GRUB hasn't been able to load the kernel so it can't go any further. _Usually_ that sort of message happens when the kernel &/or other essential boot files aren't where GRUB expects them, or if the disk they're on is unreadable for some reason. My _guess_ is that the system has "ejected" the USB after it's started to boot from it. You can see what partitions are available using the GRUB2 `ls` command (but I don't know the details since I use GRUB Legacy).

Comment: Another option that _may_ be worth trying is to use a Live USB that uses a different bootloader, eg Grub4DOS or syslinux. Puppy Linux is a very compact distro (~130 MB) that uses syslinux by default. It's slightly non-standard so it doesn't play well with generic software that creates live USBs from bootable .iso file (like UNetbootin). But it's easy to create a live USB in a running Puppy system.

Answer (score 0):

You say ANY distro fails... as such, the completeness of your question leaves much to be desired, until such time as you describe your preparation of this USB stick.  Your point of being stuck half-way into Grub is familiar--  I was having success putting Mint on a thumbdrive via Unetbootin (though actually I had to find a tweak and edit the menu.lst file manually to get it to use the USB instead of looking for a CD, since I was using a .iso (CD) image source) but that stopped working when I tried Mint 18.x which apparently switched to syslinux from the simpler Grub in the 17.x with which I had had success.
  Searching a bit, I notice the Arch brainiacs seem to favour Gummiboot for UEFI environments: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/2l5rvk/syslinux_or_grub/

Comment: Please try to better format your answers.  You should also avoid asking questions in an answer.  That is usually done in comments.  For the moment, since you don't have sufficient reputation to comment, you should stick to questions that can be answered directly.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your situation now of your problem, but i think
you are stuck in `grub bootloader`
so you can check how to boot from grub [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/390895)