# install grub from grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub

I have a virtual box hosting xubuntu. I did not have enough space anymore on the /boot partition, so I (temporary) moved the /boot/grub to /tmp in order to be able to run 'sudo apt-get -f install'.

Unfortunately, I forgot to put back the grub/ folder... (doh)

So now I can only go into the 'grub rescue' mode...

**Is there any way to fix it from there?**

[image]

As you can see I don't have any boot folder anymore!

PS: so this thread doesn't help: [Recovering from 'grub rescue>' crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash)

EDIT: I am hosting my virtual box (Xubuntu) on Windows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Chroot in your installation with an Iso or CD/DVD from installations-medium in virtualbox.

```
dpkg -l | grep grub | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -y
```

Comment: thank you, do you have any link which explain how to do that?

Comment: Only a german link, that is current.  If you have no LVM and  encryption .  You need to know the /-partiton and if you have a own /boot-partition.  `mount /dev/xxx /mnt/` for bios-installation with own boot-partition `mount /dev/xxx /mnt/boot` With efi `mount /dev/xxx /mnt/boot/efi`  This will mount the necessary virtual FS `for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt/$dir; done `  For Network-access `cp -a /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf` Now you can chroot.  `chroot /mnt/ /bin/bash` In chroot `mount -a` so all partiton in the System will be mounted.