# Gnu grub rescue screen appearing during booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I'm getting this screen immediately when i boot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eIak.jpg)

I tried the commands suggested in:
[Recovering from 'grub rescue>' crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash/148042?newreg=cbe2690075b04632b3fa137aebd50aae)

which did not work for me. Please suggest another way as soon as possible.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish before this error? Please provide more information.

Comment: I was trying to remove partitions of linux from windows. When i tried to reboot my computer after that, this happened..

Comment: What did you want to achieve? Do you want your computer to continue to have Ubuntu installed, or did you want to remove it and only use Windows?

Answer (score 2):

## Boot from a Live CD

Is it able to find your data? Then good, only the bootloader broke. Probably reinstalling GRUB will make everything work again. **No need to reinstall the whole system.**

(this is the most probably case)

On the other hand, if you are unable to see your files, that would be more serious and need further debugging. Maybe the system is unable to detect the disk (or it could have switched its order), something corrupted the partition...

Answer (score 1):

If you were removing the partition, my guess is you damaged /dev/sda or didn't set up a boot partition. Re-install the system.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? Im fine with losing everything. I just want the computer to start working again

Comment: @AjaySubramanian yeah, the only way to fix it is to re-install the system. If you don't want to spend 2 hours fiddling around with rescuing bits

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess that's the only option I have then...